# Shell Script: Generate Report Version

Tags: linux, shell, unix, aix

I am generating a report daily from the database which is basically a data extract using DB2 export.

The file format i am using is **Report_DDMMYYY.csv**

Now the issue is I need to add a version number to the report each time it is run in the same day.

For eg- **Report_24112014_001.csv || Report_24112014_002.csv**

So for each day the script is run the version keeps updating.

Any idea how i can achieve this using Shell Scripting?

Comment: I typically just use hour, minute, second.  They sort correctly and there is no guesswork involved.  As the solution below suggests, year, month, day has advantages over day, month, year that you have.  Combined, it is date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S  M is minutes while m is month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 variables. First variable will store the last execution date and the next one will store the version. Whenever you execute the script, first check if the date is same. If yes, increment the version else set the version to 1. Export the variables so that they retain their values.

```
if [ "`date +'%Y%m%d'`" == "$LAST_EXEC_DATE" ]; then 
  (( VERSION += 1 ))
else
  VERSION=1
  LAST_EXEC_DATE=`date +"%Y%m%d"`

fi
export LAST_EXEC_DATE
export VERSION
```

Comment: you don't want export $VERSION do you?  That's the same as export 3.

Comment: Also, %Y%m%d I think is what you want.

Comment: Exporting still won't make the values visible in the parent shell.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple self-contained function with a loop.

```
newfile () {
    # "local" is not POSIX, is it?
    local date
    local i
    local filename
    date=$(date +%Y%m%d)
    for ((i=1; i<=999; ++i))
        filename=$(printf 'Report_%s_%03i.csv' "$date" "$i")
        test -e "$filename" && continue
        echo "$filename"
        return 0
    done
    return 1
}
```

The loop uses Bash syntax but apart from that, it should be reasonably portable.

I use YYYYMMDD date format because I concur with several commenters that a machine-readable, sortable file format is the way to go in most situations.

Comment: This solution is better than my solution. Elegant and useful and the best part is it does not depend on storing the states in variables like my solution. +1.